# Registering to Same Receiver Multiple times

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

For some reason I need to register to same receiver multiple times like one in the Manifest and one time in the code. I want to listen package changes even the app is not running but installed.

1.In the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="PackageChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
```

2.Also in the code I register to BroadcastReceiver with the following code snippet in the constructor of.

```
public PackageChangeReceiver(@ForApplication Context context) {
    super();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
    filter.addDataScheme("package");
    context.registerReceiver(this, filter);
}
```

But somehow Android only receives one of them intermittently sometime it receives both. Is there any doc in the newer versions like a performance improvement in Android OS itself such as only receiving one broadcast although registered to multiple times. Is it device or OS or version specific thing?

Comment: Android app can have only one BroadcaseReceiver with one name. If you want multiple receivers, you can create BroadcastReceivers with different names.

Comment: Actually it is intermittently working when I put a break point and disable/enable a default application. I receive it 2 times at each. Also I have one BroadcastReceiver with one name. But I am registering two times.

Comment: I will suggest you to register your BroadcastReceiver only once. If you need it dynamically then just remove the declaration from the Android Manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Marshmallow doesn't allow multiple registration to same broadcast receiver. But if the OS version is less than or equal to LOLLIPOP_MR1, registering to same broadcast receiver is tolerable.
But since the Marshmallow(API 23) does not allow that, we can do a performance improvement like that.

```
private static final boolean REGISTER_DUPLICATE_RECEIVER = VERSION.SDK_INT <= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1;

if (REGISTER_DUPLICATE_RECEIVER) {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
        filter.addDataScheme("package");
        context.registerReceiver(this, filter);
    }
```